# ArrayList is not Thread safe even with synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I was trying Producer and Consumer problem using ArrayList(I know Arraylist isnt threadsafe), and I made sure that i put the list with `synchronized` keyword but still got into `ConcurrentModificationException`. This is the error

> Starting Producer Please provide the job details:  TestJob Job
>   completed: TestJob Exception in thread "consumer"
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException     at
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)  at
>   test.thread.Consumer.run(Consumer.java:25)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Here's my code:

```
    package test.thread;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Producer implements Runnable {

    private List<String> jobs = null;

    public Producer(List<String> jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Starting Producer");
        while(true)
        {
            synchronized (jobs) {
                try {
                if (jobs.isEmpty()) {


                        System.out.println("Please provide the job details: ");
                        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String job = scanner.nextLine();
                        jobs.add(job);
                        scanner.close();
                        jobs.notifyAll();
                        Thread.sleep(4000);

                } else {
                    jobs.wait();
                }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

}


package test.thread;

import java.util.List;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private List<String> jobs = null;

    public Consumer(List<String> list) {
        this.jobs = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true)
        {
            synchronized (jobs) {
                try {
                    if (jobs.isEmpty()) {

                        jobs.wait();

                    } else {
                        for (String job : jobs) {
                            System.out.println("Job completed: " + job);
                            jobs.remove(job);
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        }

                        jobs.notifyAll();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

    }

}



package test.thread;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestThread {

    public static void main(String...strings )
    {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Producer producer = new Producer(list);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(list);
        Thread prodThread = new Thread(producer, "producer");
        Thread consThread = new Thread(consumer, "consumer");
        prodThread.start();
        consThread.start();
    }




}
```

Comment: *All* accesses of the ArrayList must be synchronized on the same instance. This is not the case in your code (e.g. the getters and setters).

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah,  Retracted my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you get a `ConcurrentModificationException` your problem is not caused by multi-threading at all.

In fact this is the problematic code:

```
for (String job : jobs) {
    System.out.println("Job completed: " + job);
    jobs.remove(job);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

The `for` loop will use an `Iterator` over jobs and at the same time you directly (structurally) modify `jobs` (i.e. not via the `Iterator`). This means that the `Iterator` is no longer well-defined and it throws this exception to tell you about it.

If you need to remove elements from a collection while you iterate over it, you'll need to make the `Iterator` explicit:

```
Iterator<String> jobIterator = job.iterator();
while (jobIterator.hasNext()) {
  String job = jobIterator.next();
  // ... stuff ...
  jobIterator.remove(); // remove the last object that was returned by next()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot remove items from a list that you are iterating with an enhanced for statement.

If you want to remove elements, you need an explicit iterator on which to call remove:

```
Iterator<String> it = jobs.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  String job = it.next();
  System.out.println("Job completed: " + job);
  it.remove();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Of course, removing items from an ArrayList like this is very inefficient (it is `O(n^2)`), and error-prone since you have to explicitly synchronize. You should look into using some sort of `BlockingQueue` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your concurrent modification is not caused by threading.

```
    for (String job : jobs) {
                        System.out.println("Job completed: " + job);
                        jobs.remove(job);
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    }
```

The line `jobs.remove(job);` modifies the ArrayList while you are iterating over it. Iterators only allow modification of the list when done using the Iterators remove method for this.

```
     for( Iterator<String> iter = jobs.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
     {
           String job = iter.next();
           iter.remove();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You get ConcurrentModificationException not because of concurrency: you simply remove item in a loop:

```
for (String job : jobs) {
     System.out.println("Job completed: " + job);
     jobs.remove(job);
```

Use iterator to remove items.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CopyOwWriteArrayList` in order to prevent `ConcurrentModificationException` while using list `Iterator` (for-each loop in your code uses it under the hood)

Answer (score 0):

Can't remove elements while, please use the iterator method to remove.

```
Iterator<String> it = jobs.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
      String job = it.next();
      ....
      it.remove();
      ...
}
```

This will avoid concurrentModificationException.